# Finding image pixel coordinates (integers) from UV values (floats) of obj file

Tags: graphics, texture-mapping

I am parsing an obj file which contains the texture coordinates (vt) values. From what I understand, vt values are a mapping into the texture image corresponding to this obj.

Assume, I have image im = 400x300 pixels

and I have a vt value

vt .33345 .8998

The mapping says, in the image, go the coordinate :

imageWidth x .3345 , imageHeight x .8998 and use the value there.

I have loaded the image values in a 2-d array.

The problem is, these mapping coordinates are floating values, how am I suppose to map them to the integer values of the pixel coordinates ? I can always truncate the decimal part, round off etc. But does the standard defines which one of the option is to be done ?

Comment: How are you using the colors you wish to obtain? The standard way is sampling the interpolation of the uv coordinates for each point inside a triangle that is rendered on the screen, not only the corners. This is done by the openGL shader during rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uv-Coordinates are always in the range [0,1]. This means, you will get the actual pixel coordinates by multiplying them with the image size:

```
texel_coord = uv_coord * [width, height]
```

Note, that even here one gets floating point values and there are several ways how to deal with them. The most primitive one is to simply round to the next integer to get the nearest texel. A more sophisticated method would be [bilinear filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering).

Comment: Would just casting to int / truncating the decimals get the correct pixel coordinate? Wouldn't rounding inadvertently cause the answer to end up being 1 pixel off if it rounded up on a > 0.5 on a floating point value ?

Answer (score 7):

UV coordinates to Pixel coordinates :

```
pix.x = (uv.x * texture.width) -0.5
pix.y = ((1-uv.y) * texture.height) -0.5
```

The y axis of uv coordinates is opposite to the Pixel coordinates on an image.

For nearest neighbor interpolation, just round off the pixel coordinates.

For bilinear interpolation, calculate the participation percentage from the four neighbouring pixels and do a weighed average.

When UV coordinates go outside of range, there is a choice on how to handle the "texture wrapping":
[image: opengl texture Wrapping]

Here's some java code for bilinear interpolation with "repeat" texture wrapping:

```
private static int billinearInterpolation(Point2D uv, BufferedImage texture) {
    uv.x = uv.x>0 ? uv.x%1 : 1+(uv.x%1);
    uv.y = uv.y>0 ? uv.y%1 : 1+(uv.y%1);
    double pixelXCoordinate = uv.x * texture.getWidth() - 0.5;
    double pixelYCoordinate = (1-uv.y) * texture.getHeight() - 0.5;

    pixelXCoordinate = pixelXCoordinate<0?texture.getWidth()-pixelXCoordinate: pixelXCoordinate;
    pixelYCoordinate = pixelYCoordinate<0?texture.getHeight()-pixelYCoordinate : pixelYCoordinate;

    int x = (int) Math.floor(pixelXCoordinate);
    int y = (int) Math.floor(pixelYCoordinate);

    double pX = pixelXCoordinate - x;
    double pY = pixelYCoordinate - y;

    float[] px = new float[]{(float) (1 - pX), (float) pX};
    float[] py = new float[]{(float) (1 - pY), (float) pY};

    float red = 0;
    float green = 0;
    float blue = 0;
    float alpha = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < px.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < py.length; j++) {
            float p = px[i] * py[j];
            if (p != 0) {
                int rgb = texture.getRGB((x + i)%texture.getWidth(), (y + j)%texture.getHeight());
                alpha += (float) ((rgb >> 24) & 0xFF) * p;
                red += (float) ((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF) * p;
                green += (float) ((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF) * p;
                blue += (float) ((rgb >> 0) & 0xFF) * p;
            }
        }
    }
    return (((int) alpha & 0xFF) << 24) |
            (((int) red & 0xFF) << 16) |
            (((int) green & 0xFF) << 8) |
            (((int) blue & 0xFF) << 0);
}
```